# ¿Cómo escribir flechas diagonales de apoyo de determinantes matemáticas en LaTeX?

Tags: latex

Quiero escribir en LaTeX la fórmula para calcular el área de polígonos, osea:
[image: Fórmula para calcular el área de un polígono mediante coordenadas.]

- ¿Cómo puedo agregar las flechas diagonales que indiquen que elementos multiplicar? o
- ¿Cómo escribir la fórmula en LaTex? tal como se muestra en la imagen.

Comment: [tag:formulas] es para fórmulas de hoja de ´cálculo pero esta pregunta no trata sobre una aplicación de ese tipo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

con matriz de tikz puedes dibujar lineas entre los nodos, entonces puedes hacer una matriz de 3 columnas y 6 renglones
las dos primeras columnas son para tus datos, en la ultima columna el signo
en el primer y ultimo renglon, solo necesitas la ultima columna, asi que pones && para saltar las primeras dos columnas

Como la matriz queda mas grande de lo que en realidad es, no puedes usar los limitadores que ya vienen con la matriz, los dibujas con:

```
     \draw (M-2-1.north west) -- (M-5-1.south west) ;
     \draw (M-2-2.north east) -- (M-5-2.south east) ;
```

la primera linea dibuja una linea del nodo (2,1) de tu matriz, al nodo (5,1)
con north west, indicas que quieres que empiese desde la parte de arriba del nodo y del lado izquierdo, con south west,que termine en la parte de abajo y del lado izquierdo

para el limitador del lado derecho es lo mismo, pero con east para que quede del lado derecho del nodo, y cambias la cordenada "y" del nodo para que este despues de la ultima linea de tu matriz

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

      \matrix (M) [matrix of math nodes , inner sep=2pt, row sep=1cm,column sep=16mm]{
       && -\\      
       x1 & y1 & - \\
       x2 & y2  & -\\ 
       x3 & y3 & + \\
       x1 & y1 & + \\
       && +\\  
       };


     \draw (M-2-1.north west) -- (M-5-1.south west) ;
     \draw (M-2-2.north east) -- (M-5-2.south east) ;

     \draw(M-2-1)--(M-3-2)--(M-4-3);
     \draw(M-3-1)--(M-4-2)--(M-5-3);
     \draw(M-4-1)--(M-5-2)--(M-6-3);

      \draw(M-5-1)--(M-4-2)--(M-3-3);
      \draw(M-4-1)--(M-3-2)--(M-2-3);
      \draw(M-3-1)--(M-2-2)--(M-1-3);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Medio cochinon pero jala xD